# ajaxForm submit not working for file upload in IE9

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, yii, ajaxform

I have been trying to submit a form using ajax and formData. But it was not working in IE9.

Finally I found that IE9 does not support formData. Then I changed submitting the form using ajaxSubmit. But this also not working for file upload.

But I am getting an error in IE console that 'Type error' access denied.

Here is my code.

```
      $("#link-categories-form").ajaxSubmit({
         url: '<?php echo Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl("Categories/updatecategory"); ?>?           id=' + id,
         success: function (data) {
            if (data == "success") {
               alert('success');
            }
            else {
               alert('error);
         },
         error: function (data) { // if error occured
            alert("Error occured.please try again");
            alert(data);
         }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$("#link-categories-form").ajaxSubmit({
     url: '<?php echo Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl("Categories/updatecategory"); ?>?id=' + id,
     success: function (data) {
        if (data == "success") {
           alert('success');
        }
        else {
           alert('error');
        }
     },
     error: function (data) { // if error occured
        alert("Error occured.please try again");
        alert(data);
     }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help..May I know what was the change you made in the code?

Comment: You forgot to close the first else statement with "}". The alert('error); needs to be change with alert('error');

Comment: Thanks..doing that helped to work the code in Mozilla and chrome...But file upload not working in IE9..